# Issue reading text file separated with |#|

Tags: pandas, dataframe, txt

I'm trying to read a .txt file separated with |#|. Looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5emab.jpg .  I have tried pd.read_csv("df.txt", sep="||#||", error_bad_lines=False) and "|#|" too, but with no result. It shows up completely broken, placing every letter in a different column. Also, the database has no headers. Any ideas?

Here's the output I'm getting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXZVU.jpg

Comment: Does it work if you use `pd.read_csv("df.txt", sep='|#|', error_bad_lines=False, engine='python')`? Based on [Pandas : Read csv file to Dataframe with custom delimiter in Python](https://thispointer.com/pandas-read-csv-file-to-dataframe-with-custom-delimiter-in-python/).

Comment: No. It keeps placing every character in another column. Like this: https://imgur.com/a/vz6dxpA

Comment: Please do not post [images of code/text](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: How about escaping it like `\|#\|`? If it treating it as a regex, then the pipes need to be escaped.